# Python MySQLdb insert with TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

I failed to insert records to mysql via python as below:

```
songs = ['abc','bbb']

for i in songs:

      cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE (%s)", i)
```

I got an error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187,
>   in execute
>       query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

My troubleshooting steps:

1. Insert separate:

   `cur.execute('INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE ("haha")')`

--> succeed

2. Insert by "for" script only with one character in the list:

   `songs = ['a','b','c']`

   `for i in songs:`

   ```
   `cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE (%s)", i)`
   ```

---> succeed

Comment: You need to use `VALUES` not `VALUE`

Comment: `INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES (%s)`

Comment: May be - `cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE ('%s')" %i)`. but not a good approach

Comment: @kuro thanks, this also works.

Comment: Current solutions:
cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES ('%s')" %i)
---------------------------------------------------

cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE ('%s')" %i)
----------------------------------------------------


cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES ('%s')" %(i,))
-----------------------------------------------------------

cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUE ('%s')" %(i,))
--------------------------------------------------


both VALUE and VALUES works

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to follow you approach, try -

```
songs = ['a','b','c']

for i in songs:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES ('%s')" %(i,))
#Use commit here or turn auto-commit on
```

Take a look at this link -

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.
If I set 
songs = ['a','b','c']

My original method also works.
I I change it to be:
songs = ['aa','bb','cc']

your method works, do you know the root cause?

Comment: @RoyZeng, glad it helps

Comment: One more question: cur.executemany fail:   cur.executemany("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES('%s')", [('aaa'),('bbb')])

succeed with:

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO song (title,year) VALUES (%s, %s)",[('aaa',2000),('bbb',2001)])

Comment: Try - `cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES('%s'),('%s')" %('aaa','bbb'))`

Comment: It works.
We have to separate the values, if insert for one column.

Comment: This is bad practice. It is unsafe, as it does not escape the values being passed in. Think about what would happen if I set `i`to `'); DROP TABLE song;`

Comment: @JamieCockburn, that is why I said **If you want to follow you approach**. I even said that it is not good approach in my comment

Comment: @kuro
Could you show me best practice? I tried cur.executemany(sql_command,list_data), but still failed.

Comment: @RoyZeng, can you look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Answer (score 3):

Using a string like that as the second argument doesn't work. The issue here is that the second argument to `execute()` should be a sequence (a list, tuple, etc.). A string is itself a sequence of characters: `['a', 'b', 'c']`

In your example, the first character (`a`) is taken as the first format argument (`%s`). After that, the rest of the string is considered "too many" arguments.

You need to pass a sequence where the first item is the string:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES (%s)", (i,))
```

This says format with the tuple (sequence) containing one element, `i`.

Note this is different to @kuro's answer, because it is allowing the library to correctly escape the values, which is safer, and handles different value types correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO song (title) VALUES (%s)", i)
```